# How should I exclude state resources from being deleted when redeploying to a new Kubernetes cluster with Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I want to redeploy to a new cluster using the terraform destroy command, but I want to keep the state resources managed outside the cluster like "google_storage_bucket".
How can I exclude some resources from being deleted?
Or is there a better practice to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `destroy` command, **all** resources from terraform state are planned to be destroyed.
I assume you are talking about the bucket that is also a part of terraform code, but not a part of a cluster that was created using this code.
The best option would be to delete only the resources you want to be destroyed using:

```
terraform apply -destroy -target=resource.to_be_destroyed
# example:
terraform apply -destroy -target=google_container_cluster.main
```

which means the destroy plan is going to be only about those specific resource (you can add a couple at the same time using more `-target` flags).

The other option is to use `-replace` option. This marks a module or resource to be recreated in next apply, example:

```
terraform apply -replace=module.gke
```

Sources:

- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#replace-address
- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#resource-targeting